# Are there any audio/video libraries for Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know of an audio/video library that supports Python 3, or a way to play audio files with Python 3 successfully?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for libraries to Python, look at http://pypi.python.org/ There is a page for libraries that have Python 3 support (but it's not complete, not all libraries that support Python 3 are marked as such): http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all

You can also click yourself through all the categories to find packages. That way you can find all Multimedia-Audio packages that support Python 3:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=214&c=338&c=352&c=533

And Video:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=214&c=338&c=367&c=533

The list isn't that impressive in either case. If you must use Python 3, find the libraries you *do* want, contact the authors and help them port to Python 3. It's fun, and you'll learn more about Python than you thought there was to know! :-)

Otherwise, use Python 2. It's still a couple of years before Python 3 will have enough libraries to be generally useful unless you want to port libraries.